# Kill Minecraft Player if he touches a block

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I want to code a plugin, that kills the player if he touches a block. It's for an ice race game. The players can easily cheat and just walk and don't drive with the boat. So I got the idea to code a plugin that kills the player. I'm using spigot 1.16.5.

```
public class icetouch implements Listener {
   @EventHandler
   public void onTouch(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
       Player p = event.getPlayer();
       if (p.getLocation().getBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN).getType() == Material.ICE) {
          p.setHealth(0);
       }
   }
}
```

In Console it says failed to execute event.

Here is how i registered it:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
   PluginManager pluginManager = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
   pluginManager.registerEvents(new icetouch(), this);
}
```

Full Error log:

```
[23:29:58] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerMoveEvent to PenguBlockTouch v1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: null

Comment: Can you show full logs ?

Comment: I added the full log

Comment: Thanks that's helping, but there is no more lines ? strange

Comment: With only your code that you show, for me it works fine. The error you are getting doesn't come from this, and we can't help you with only this part of error

Comment: fixed it. Maybe can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905438/how-can-i-check-if-the-player-is-in-a-boat

Comment: I think yes, I can. And that's fine it you fix it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered it wrong.
Use:

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new icetouch(), this);
```